# Clustering with predefined centers on an image

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, classification, k-means

How can I use clustering algorithms say K-Means with predefined centroids?
or if you can recommend better solutions for my problem which is substituting all pixels in an image from RGB to the nearest predefined colors in :{blue, red, green, yellow, orange}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change the color of a pixel to the nearest predefined color than there is no need for k-means.

1. Go over all the pixels in the image:
2. For each pixel measure the euclidean distance to each on of the predefined colors
3. Assign the new pixel value according to the closest predefined color found in 2.

Comment: I already tried it but it would take too much time since it's running on raspberryPi

Comment: Than downsample the image do the algorithm above and than upsample back to the original resolution.

Comment: Thanks a lot :like:

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to understand you.
if you want to transform a mono channel image into a RGB image using this palette it is not a classification nor a k-means problem.
To do this you can create a lut table corresponding to your palette and apply it to your grey scale image

Comment: I mean, I receive a standard image from a camera for example, now I need to cluster this image using the centers I defined